# HTML not recognizing a controller in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-controller

I am following a video tutorial video for Angular JS and started the topic of using a controller as syntax.  The example I am working on yields a different result from the one in the tutorial, however.  My code (below) outputs the following error:

```
angular.js:13550 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ParentController' is not a function, got undefined
```

I am confused as to why this is happening since I copied the code verbatim from the tutorial and still get the error while the tutorial's code output seems fine.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="ParentController">
        <p>This is the parent: {{ parentMessage }}</p>
        <div ng-controller="FirstChild">
            <p>My parent is: {{ parentMessage }}</p>
            <p>The first child is: {{ firstMessage }}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="SecondChild">
            <p>My parent is: {{ parentMessage }}</p>
            <p>The second child is: {{ secondMessage }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.model('myApp').controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.parentMessage = 'What she said.';}]);

angular.model('myApp').controller('FirstChild', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.firstMessage = 'I want my mother.';}]);

angular.model('myApp').controller('SecondChild', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.secondMessage = 'I want my father.';}]);
```

The reason the error is appearing is because the HTML code isn't able to find the ParentController, FirstChild and SecondChild functions as functions in the JS code.  The reason this is bothering me is because when I attempt a similar parent/child JS/HTML code pair then the error doesn't appear.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="First">
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">
        <p>This is the first controller: {{model.name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="Second">
        <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">
        <p>This is the second controller: {{model.name}}</p>
    </div>  
</body>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp').service('SharedService',function(){
    return {name: 'Uncle Alvin'};});

angular.module('myApp').controller('First',['$scope', 'SharedService', function($scope, SharedService){
        $scope.model = SharedService;}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('Second',['$scope', 'SharedService', function($scope, SharedService){
        $scope.model = SharedService;}]);
```

I am not convinced that using shared services is the reason the latter pair of code works while the former doesn't.  I want to know what is causing the HTML to not recognize the ng-controllers in the first instance and how I should go about modifying the pair to make them recognizable.

I apologize if this post is redundant to another topic that I couldn't find on my own.  If it is, feel free to link the most original/helpful posting of this issue.

Comment: Whoops.  The answer is that I used 'model' instead of 'module'.

Comment: could you share which tutorial is this?

Comment: @nerezo  It's offered exclusively through Robert Half International (RHI) to registered programming consultants.  The bit I was working on was for learning how to implement controllers as syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for controllers not working in the first module is,

(i) Not `model` it is `module`

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

and it is easy if you dont declare it thrice, declare once and add the controllers.

```
var myApp= angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.parentMessage = 'What she said.';}]);

myApp.controller('FirstChild', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.firstMessage = 'I want my mother.';}]);

myApp.controller('SecondChild', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.secondMessage = 'I want my father.';}]);
```

Comment: the module actually hasn't been declared in the OP snippet. `angular.module('abc', [])` will declare it (note the brackets `[]`) whereas subsequent `angular.module('abc')` will fetch the reference. This is standard and there is no need to save the module in a global variable or declare everything in a single chain.

Comment: @WilliamB  thats the same thing i have explained

Comment: No, you said he is declaring it 3 times. It is declared 0 times in the original post. `var myApp = angular.module` is not needed

Comment: @WilliamB hmm , i guess OP's issue is with the name , he has put it model instead of module

Comment: @Sajeetharan  Yep, just noticed the typo myself.  The code works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example on how to do it.

Took this example from w3schools

First Name: 
Last Name: 

Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>
```